# CKeditor add image properties advanced tab

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How do you add Advanced properties tab to CKeditor 'Image' button dialog?

I copied this plugin to my plugins folder and followed instructions to add it in config.js and in comments in link below but does not show the 'Advanced' tab.

config.extraPlugins = 'dialogadvtab';

http://ckeditor.com/addon/dialogadvtab

Someone in the comments suggested these steps which did not seem to work:

- Go to the plugins\someplugin\someplugin.js file
- Right after the "CKEDITOR.dialog.add('textarea', function (editor) {" line add "var dialogadvtab = editor.plugins.dialogadvtab;"
- Then scroll to the bottom and look for the last "]" charactor.
- Before it add ", dialogadvtab && dialogadvtab.createAdvancedTab(editor, null, 'table')"

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*... yes, I know, that question was years ago. But this page was one of the first hits in the search engine during my own search for a solution ...*

In the config.js I saw that by default exactly this tab is removed!

```
// Simplify the dialog windows.
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
```

A change in the config.js had no effect on my installation, so I overwrote the parameter with empty directly when creating the editor.
Additionally I recommend the parameter allowedContent, so that "class" and other properties can be processed.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                                 allowedContent: true,
                                 extraPlugins: 'dialogadvtab',
                                 removeDialogTabs: ''
                             }
 );
```